# State with custom query parameters outside state declaration

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router.
I've got state like `company.add` - `url: 'company/add/'`

I want to pass parameters to fill form a bit (ex. city or postalcode).

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define query parameters like url parameters:

```
angular.module("app").config(["$stateProvider", function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("company.add", {
        url: "/company/add?city",
        templateUrl: "loginTpl.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
    });
}]);
```

Reference the state:

```
ui-sref="company.add({city: 'YourCity'})"
```

Access via controller:

```
$stateParams.city
```

Comment: But this solution isn't flexible - what if I want to use postalcode or street as param? What if I want to use every param? Do I have to construct every possibility?

Comment: You can also use arrays in query parameters, which you can pass dynamically.

Comment: Can You give example of those arrays?